# Can a Xamarin.Mac app be compiled to run on Windows?

Tags: xamarin.mac

Seems like an obvious question however the answer is not plainly discoverable on the Xamarin website.  If I develop a Xamarin app on the Mac, using Visual Studio for Mac, and developing in C#, can the result be compiled/built to run on Windows?

Comment: Xamarin.Mac apps require macOS only APIs, such as `UIKit`, to run. Even though you can copy the files to Windows, and the program might be initialized there, it would obviously fail when the first call to macOS API is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not compile and run a complete Xamarin.Mac app on windows.

The basic idea with xamarin is that you split UI and non UI code. The UI part uses native API's and is not portable. But most non UI code you can share between platforms.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You can re-use resulting portable .NET libraries which you compiled on different platform.

Comment: So you mean I can't re-use resulting portable .NET libraries which I built on Windows?  How are they 'portable' then?